# Using kibana and mongodb together without elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, user-interface, frontend, logstash, kibana

Is it possible to use kibana front-end along with a mongodb back-end without using elastic search?

I'm using logstash to parse logs and store in mongodb and want to use kibana to display data?

If not, are there any alternatives to implement kibana+mongodb?

Comment: mongoDB charts are about to launch

Comment: MongoDB Charts -- https://www.mongodb.com/products/charts

Comment: Mongo charts is non-free, doesn't support client-side SSL, is deprecated as an on-prem solution. It's only a feature in Mongo Atlas now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm afraid that Kibana is specifically designed to use the Elasticsearch API.
While they do both provide JSON responses, they don't return compatible data structures and even if they did, Mongo would not provide the same features (facets/filters) that Kibana makes heavy use of.

You could probably index your MongoDB data in Elasticsearch following instructions similar to https://coderwall.com/p/sy1qcw but then you are unnecessarily duplicating your data in 2 systems.

Comment: There are no options but to duplicate data. Mongo charts is broken and can't run on-prem. mongosqld doesn't work for most bi tools, such as Apache subset. Can someone suggest an actual free and open source BI tool that works with an on-prem Mongo?

Comment: @Philluminati you can use apache drill to transform mongodb data into superset. check this: https://www.shubhamdipt.com/blog/mongodb-to-apache-drill-to-apache-superset/